# How to change a field from index = false to index = true in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field that was originally set to `"index": false` because we did not think we would ever have to query on this particular field. Its now about 9 months later and we have a new feature request that is going to require us to query on this field.

I know ES offers some nice features like `fields` that allow you to add more functionality to a field, but it does not appear to allow you to go from `index = false` to `index = true` by simply adding a sub-field.

After some googling I was not able to find a solution to this issue that doesn't involve either 1) creating a new field altogether or 2) re-indexing all of the data.

Does anyone know of a clean/side effect-free way of adding this kind of functionality to an existing field? If not, what is the suggested process?

Here is what the current field looks like:

```
{
  "mappings": {
      "entity": {
        "properties": {
          "contentType": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "index": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Like I said I am looking to find the cleanest way of changing `"index"` to `true`

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, the existing mapping is immutable and that's why you're only seeing those two approaches

Comment: Ahh really... ok so between those two options, creating a new field is probably the best option for getting things working ASAP.

Comment: How much content do you have? Reindexing is probably the ideal choice, but you're right, adding a new field that is the same data that can be returned with the source is probably your easiest solution.

Comment: We have about 15TB of data over 9.4 billion docs so its not ideal to re-index :|. I think adding a new field and then later removing the old one and using the Rename Processor is the best option for us.

Comment: Yeah that's quite a lot of data, I think you're right here. I take it you only need the source returned from new additions, not existing content?

Comment: Unfortunealy we DO need existing documents to work with this new field as well. Our ES index stores metadata of documents and only gets updated when we detect a "diff" between our data and the data on the source, so we can utilize that part of our pipeline to force re-indexing of this field.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new index and reindex I’m afraid.

Reindex API can be a great help though.